# MS Publisher cannot save the file to PDF with crop marks

Tags: pdf, printing, microsoft-publisher

I am unable to save (i.e. export) the file to PDF using MS Publisher, when I include crop marks in my printout.

[image]

Saving the file otherwise works, but when I include crop marks, it simply fails with a generic message "Cannot save the file". It doesn't offer any additional troubleshooting options that I am aware of.

Has anyone had similar problems before, or a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, I solved my problem by *printing* to PDF (instead of using the Publishers "native" Save to PDF). I enabled crop marks in advanced output settings and used [PDF Creator](http://www.pdfforge.org/) (but probably any PDF capture driver will do).

[image]

The results may differ a bit for more complex elements, but PDF Creator files are actually generally smaller (having image compression and downsampling disabled on both sides).

But I did have situations where PDF Creator was unable to render some elements properly, and this is why I tried avoid this path initially.